# What kind of graph I need for Dijkstra's algorithm? C++

Tags: c++, graph, dijkstra, weighted-graph

I am trying to learn some more stuff about graphs and Dijkstra's Algorithm, so I have a function that randomly generates a weighted undirected graph, saves in a file like this:

```
numbers_of_vertices number_of_nodes
node_a node_b distance_from_a_to_b
etc.
```

And then I run Dijkstra's to output the distances from node 0 to all the other nodes, but sometimes the distance from node 0 to other nodes is 0, that means that there is no connection from node 0 to that node?
Also I have another question, with what kind of graphs Dijkstra's works?>br>
Thanks for the help!

Comment: If a distance of zero means there is no connection, then do not consider such nodes when running Dijkstra's algorithm on your graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dijkstra's algorithm is a variation of a BFS traversal. The difference is, it utilizes a min heap to traverse to the closest node every time.

Your function that randomly generates a weighted undirected graph should not create a pair of nodes where node_a and node_b have a distance of 0. This means the node is in the same exact place - thus, no need to traverse.

Dijkstra's algorithm works on any weighted graphs (with positive only weights) where you have a starting and an end condition.

Here's a 10 minute video explaining the algorithm:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pVfj6mxhdMw